# RavenDB Python Client UseOptimisticConcurrency, does this option exist?

Tags: python, ravendb

Recently I have started to work with python RavenDB client, and found out that documentation for the python client is not full. Official page even does not contain Python as an option for the doceumentation.
Anyhow, official client is there and I wanted to understand if it contains something like "session.Advanced.UseOptimisticConcurrency", I tried to look into coding and did not find anything like this. Does anybody know about it? Mabye it is turned on by default?

The docuemtnation for the python does not contain any hint.

Comment: Didn't find any tests for this, but `__use_optimistic_concurrency` seems to be supported in the client code. See these links:

https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb-python-client/blob/4f779225a4faeeb3ce4e77ab75791c0cc4d2c145/ravendb/documents/conventions.py#L39
 
https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb-python-client/blob/4f779225a4faeeb3ce4e77ab75791c0cc4d2c145/ravendb/documents/session/document_session_operations/in_memory_document_session_operations.py#L1081C34-L1081C34

Answer (score 2):

This [option](https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb-python-client/blob/f5328409a510960d5954ddd207d398ca53797c66/ravendb/documents/conventions.py#L39) can be set in your `DocumentConventions`.

You can set a [property](https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb-python-client/blob/215f965dd22405db5c868407514cdb95ca070bb5/ravendb/documents/store/definition.py#L87-L96) of your `DocumentStore` with your custom document conventions.

Then upon internal/automatic `RequestExecutor` creation, the conventions will be passed forward to be processed.